# Method of Substitution in Differential Equation Involving Two Independent Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How should I do the substitution when it involves two independent variables simultaneously? I have encountered the following equation in a paper and have no idea how it works:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[\frac1n\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac{c}{n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}\right]=-2\sigma cn\left[\frac1n\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac{c}{n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}\right]$$
In the above equation, $n$ is a function of $x$ and $t$, and $c$, $\sigma$ are constants. $x$ and $t$ are independent variables.

The author then uses 
$$\xi=\frac{x}{c}, \rho=t-\frac{x}{c}.$$
for substitution. The first substitution is easy to understand, so that it reduces to:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[\frac1n \frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac1n\frac{\partial n}{\partial \xi}\right]=-2\sigma c\left(\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial n}{\partial \xi}\right).$$
I don't know how the second substitution works, the equation is further reduced to the following format according to the paper:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}\left[\frac1n \frac{\partial n}{\partial\xi}\right]=-2\sigma c\,\frac{\partial n}{\partial \xi}.$$

Comment: Is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[\frac1n\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac{c}{n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}\right]=-2\sigma cn\left[\frac1n\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac{c}{n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}\right]$$ really the original PDE?

Comment: You say $n=n(x,t),$ and then you list $n$ as a constant. Is there more than one $n?$

Comment: Sorry Adrian, it is my mistake, $n$ is not a constant, it is a function of $x$ and $t$.